# setInterval code not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML:

```
<body onclick = 'myMove(event)'>
    <p>
    <button onclick="myMove(event)">Go Right</button>
    </p>
    <div id ="animate"></div>
    <p id='para'>HI</p>
</body>
```

This JavaScript:

```
function myMove(event) {
  let elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = event.clientX;
  let id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  let pos = elem.style.marginLeft;

  function frame() {
    if (pos === event.clientX) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
```

But every time it runs, the box goes to the start and then moves to my mouse position. Is there a way to make it go to the mouse position from wherever it is and not go back to the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script>
 let pos = null;
function myMove(event) {
  let elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = event.clientX;
  let id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  if(pos === null){
   pos = elem.style.marginLeft;
  }
 

  function frame() {
    if (pos === event.clientX ) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else if(pos < event.clientX){
      
      pos++;
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
    else{
      pos--;
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
 }
</script>

<body onclick = 'myMove(event)'>
    <p>
    <button onclick="myMove(event)">Go Right</button>
    </p>
    <div style='position:relative;' id ="animate">aaa</div>
    <p id='para'>HI</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems.
1. Function frame must be declared before calling setinterval
2. The variables `id` and `pos` are not in scope for `frame`. So they too should be declared globally within the main function `myMove`.

```
function myMove(event) {
    let id;
    let pos;
    let frame = function() {
        if (pos === event.clientX) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          pos++;
          elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
      }
    let elem = document.getElementById("animate");
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = event.clientX;
    let id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    let pos = elem.style.marginLeft;
}
```